# Why am I receiving this error, "Error: object 'folder' not found"?

Tags: r

Code for R is below, I am not sure why it is not finding the object folder.
I start by Unzipping the tar file with the untar() function. Then Create a training folder that contains the 20news-bydate-train data, make function that reads folders, and create a data frame to hold the title of the newsgroup, the message id, and the text that goes with it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

url <- "http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/20news-bydate.tar.gz"
download.file(url, destfile = "20news-bydate.tar.gz")
untar("20news-bydate.tar.gz")

training_folder <- "20news-bydate-train"

# Create a function to read all files from a folder into a data frame
read_folder <- function(infolder) {
  data_frame(file = dir(infolder, full.names = TRUE)) %>%
    mutate(text = map(file, read_lines)) %>%
    transmute(id = basename(file), text) %>%
    unnest(text)
}

# Use unnest() and map() to apply read_folder to each subfolder
(raw_text <- data_frame(folder = dir(training_folder, full.names = TRUE)) %>%
    unnest(map(folder, read_folder)) %>%
    transmute(newsgroup = basename(folder), id, text))
```

Comment: R generally tends to be restrictive about objects beginning with numeral like things, wherein if resolved to strings and then evaluated, something like 20... might not work right. Perhaps destfile, training_folder might suffer a renaming to 20 at the end or something if 20 is really necessary for future comprehension and differentiation from further downloads. Just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: The library(readr) is needed for the **read_lines** function used within the **read_folder** function. This was missing in the question*. The author does not know the precise answer to the question "Why am I receiving the error". Following is an attempt to solve the problem instead.

---

**Most likely problem:**
When applying unnest() on a dataframe, it must first be mutated. The questioner probably used the functionality as it existed before it was depricated. Adding this small step, ensured that the data got processed without any error.

**Potential solution:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)

url <- "http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/20news-bydate.tar.gz"
download.file(url, destfile = "20news-bydate.tar.gz")
untar("20news-bydate.tar.gz")

training_folder <- "20news-bydate-train"

# Create a function to read all files from a folder into a data frame
read_folder <- function(infolder) {
  data_frame(file = dir(infolder, full.names = TRUE)) %>%
    mutate(text = map(file, read_lines)) %>%
    transmute(id = basename(file), text) %>%
    unnest(text)
}

raw_text <- data_frame(folder = dir(training_folder, full.names = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(temp = map(folder, read_folder)) %>%
  unnest(temp) %>%
  transmute(newsgroup = basename(folder), id, text)
```

convert to dataframe

```
raw_text_df <- as.data.frame(raw_text)
```

Output looks like this:

```
> print(head(raw_text_df ))
    newsgroup    id                                                               text
1 alt.atheism 49960                                 From: mathew <mathew@mantis.co.uk>
2 alt.atheism 49960                        Subject: Alt.Atheism FAQ: Atheist Resources
3 alt.atheism 49960    Summary: Books, addresses, music -- anything related to atheism
4 alt.atheism 49960 Keywords: FAQ, atheism, books, music, fiction, addresses, contacts
5 alt.atheism 49960                             Expires: Thu, 29 Apr 1993 11:57:19 GMT
6 alt.atheism 49960                                                Distribution: world
```

Hope it helps.